# Is there the difference between "symbols" and "characters" in programming?

Tags: naming, variables

I want to select between "symbol(s)" and "character(s)" for my variables' names in cases when these terms are synonyms. Please teach me some information which allows to make this choice.

### Frequent use cases

1. `MINIMAL_SYMBOLS_COUNT`/`MINIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT`
2. `MAXIMAL_SYMBOLS_COUNT`/`MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT`
3. `EXACT_SYMBOLS_COUNT`/`EXACT_CHARACTERS_COUNT`
4. `ALLOWED_SYMBOLS`/`ALLOWED_CHARACTERS`

```
const MINIMAL_SYMBOLS_COUNT: number = 5;
const ALLOWED_SYMBOLS: number = [ 1, 0 ];

function removeLastSymbol(): string { /* */ }
function removeLastCharacter(): string { /* */ }
```

Comment: Words mean what you want them to mean. From what you posted your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @gnasher729, it has been answered, anyway. I knew what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*strings* are collections of *characters* The term "symbol" is not used to mean a letter/number/symbol in a string.

From the naming of your variables it looks to me like you should NOT use the word "symbol", you should use "character".

I would only use symbol if I had a defined set of characters which were all symbols, eg mathematical operators, planetary astronomical symbols, names of pop stars trolling their record labels some such.

Comment: I can absolutely not see how you draw the conclusion, because there is nothing in the question giving me any clue whether symbols or characters are meant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Thanks to, now I can make the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Symbol refers to something semantically higher level that characters. In a programming language characters are meaningless until they form a statement, a keyword, an operator, an identifier, a constant or a value. What a symbol is exactly varies over languages and/or compiler implementations. In the Microsoft world they relate to debugging, they map points in a compiled program to source code locations.

I found this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/symbols) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is open to interpretation in multiple different ways because the term 'symbol' has no single universal definition.

In the context of 'characters' there is a connection to 'symbols', i.e. the shapes and glyphs you see as a human which appear to you on a display device as something that you might recognise as text, numbers, punctuation, emojis, etc.

A key aspect of the term 'character' is that it typically refers to a construct which has a well-defined, direct electronic representation using integers (e.g. based on character sets such as UTF8 or ASCII), so is often treated as a primitive construct in programming languages.

The term 'symbol', while being ambiguous, could be seen in the context of text characters as referring to visual glyphs or shapes on a visual display or output device (or even sequences/collections of shapes, such as words or multi-character operators); meaningful to humans but generally meaningless or at least very hard for computers to understand the shapes/patterns by themselves -- i.e. computers have no idea what the various pixel-patterns or colours actually mean.

That is to say, it would typically require some reasonably sophisticated image/text recognition algorithm to determine that a pixel pattern shaped as `A` should indeed be interpreted as an ASCII or Unicode integer for `'A'` (and that interpretation may even have a small chance to fail).

The term 'symbol' is not clearly defined, but a common concept behind the term is that it refers to human-relatable semantics rather than electronic representation.

In addition, not all electronic characters are associated with symbols; for example, `EOF` is a non-printable control character which is used to denote the end of a byte stream -- it's really handy for electronic devices but useless to humans.

If I were to take a guess about the example code in the question, I might wonder whether white-space characters (tab/space/newline/CR) could also be excluded from the definition of "symbol" being that humans generally use whitespace for separation/layout/formatting, but this would be a matter of consulting the documentation and understanding what the original programmer meant by the term "symbol" -- people frequently choose unclear, ambiguous and misleading names in their code.